# ensemble methods:voting with average of probabilities in weka

Tags: probability, classification, data-mining, weka, ensemble-learning

output attribute is risky patient. Values are yes and no.if yes then patient is risky and if no then patient is not risky.

If I am combining 3 classifier for classification model in weka, and if final result will be calculated by average voting

For Exp: Classifier 1 result- yes, Classifier 2 result- no, Classifier 3 result- yes,

count of yes=2, count of no=1

final result will be yes as it's count is high. This is understandable.

But if I am combing 2 classifier,

For Exp: Classifier 1 result-yes, Classifier 2 result-no

count of yes=1, count of no=1

Now, What will be result? as yes and no has same count value.

How is weka working in case of this kind of combination of two multiple classifier? It's really confusing..